# how to show number of cell in table view using label

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have one table view which contains more that many results which will dipslay in each cell. Totally i have 50 data in table view. I did some array and display that in table view.Like this :

```
var tableData = ["thomas", "Alva", "Edition", "sathish", "mallko", "techno park" ..... till 50 data]
```

What i need is, i have one label called `countlabel`. Now i need to display how much data in my tableview is there? in my lbel `countLabel`. i need to dipslay in my label is  `50 datas`.... Because i am having 50 data in my table view. PLease help me how to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Doug you have any idea about UITalbeView?

Comment: do you mean you want a simple count displayed somewhere on the view - like @DarthVader has provided, or do you need something within the tableView, perhaps with each row containing a label like "row 1 of 50" ?

Comment: What you return in `tableview(...numberOfRowsInSection)` is the count of your table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
countLabel.text = "\(tableData.count) data"
```